# NSolid Apps In Docker Containers register wrong IP

Tags: node.js, docker, nsolid

I'm deploying a bunch of node apps in docker containers and trying to use N|Solid to monitor them. However, the process in the container is using the internal ip address of the container( `172.17.0.1` ). Which makes sense technically, but the those IPs are not resolvable and the UI never picks them up.

Is there a way to tell the process the IP address to use? Environment variable or something

Answer (score 2):

Will with NodeSource here.

Yes. This is a bit of a problem. We have a set of N|Solid Docker Images baking in the oven that address this.

For now, the best way to get N|Solid to work with Docker is to create a network using `docker network create nsolid`, and run the N|Solid proxy, console, and etcd all in docker containers on that network using `docker run --net nsolid`.

When you add a container to the network, it will grab the ip address and register it with etcd. Since everything is on the same network, the proxy will be able to use that ip address to reach the N|Solid agent.

If you want to try out the N|Solid Docker Images we are baking, shoot me an email at wblankenship@nodesource.com

Comment: That only works if they are all running on the same host. We are running coreos and the etcd instance comes with the os and isn't in a container.

They machines year run process also have etcd instances set up as proxies to a dedicated cluster. Not sure if that matters.

The docker network thing is nice for developing, that is what we do actually. But we don't do that in the real world.

Comment: Yes. We have been solving this by using the overlay driver for network when using multi-host configurations.